# Software removal without Synaptic or dpkg for manually built software

Tags: ubuntu-netbook

I have a Ubuntu system with a mix of softwares that were installed either by

- synaptic/dpkg
- manual built and install

However, I would now like to remove those software that were manually built and installed. Is there a systematic way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sudo make uninstall
```

It removes the manually build/installed software, it needs to be executed on the same folder it was originally builded upon.
Another version of the sources should not work correctly, so you have to keep the original sources folder.

TIP: THATS why i recommend replacing `sudo make install` by `sudo checkinstall` which makes an easy to remove .DEB file

Comment: Thanks! That helped alot! And thanks for the checkinstall as well ... I think I'll use that more often now. Cheers!

Comment: added bonus of checkinstall is that if it isn't debianized or defined properly (like if there is no make checkinstall there's probably no make uninstall target) in the make file, you know before you need make uninstall.